# sslv3 alert handshake failure on wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, ssl, smtp, ssl-certificate

I have 8 websites on wordpress on a shared hosting, from last few days, my send inquiry page is not working due to SSL V3 error, i am using `WP-SMTP` and `CONTACT FORM 7` plugins. can any one suggest me what is the issue.

I asked to the host provider, and they replied me to contact Plugin Developer.

error is like as mentioned below:

```
Warning: stream_socket_enable_crypto(): SSL operation failed with code 1. 
OpenSSL Error messages: error:14094410:SSL 
routines:SSL3_READ_BYTES:sslv3 alert handshake failure in /home/xyz/public_html/xyz.com/wp-includes/class-smtp.php on line 344
```

Comment: Quote a minimum complete example of the code that shows the problem.  We can't help you without that!

Answer (score 0):

The WP-SMTP plugin is trying to communicate with whatever SMTP server you have configured over SSL V3. Recently the web has been moving away from SSL V3 due to security concerns. You will want to see if there is another way you can configure your WP-SMTP plugin to connect to your mail server.  That plugin does have a "test email" button that will speed up your configuration testing.